# Get event parameters via reflection

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection

I can't work out how to get the parameter types for an event.

For instance, I can only see using a MethodInfo to get parameters, but I have either an EventInfo or a FieldInfo.

What I want is to be able to get 'Boolean' from this:

```
Public Event EventName(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal value As Boolean)
```

I could theoretically try something like GetRaiseMethod() but that won't work (because that method returns null as per [this link](http://bytes.com/groups/net/398128-eventinfo-getraisemethod-always-returns-null)) and even if it did it would require a method binding first and this is meant to be for a test suite just confirming that the event has a certain typed parameter at initialisation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the type of the second parameter as follows assuming the event `EventName` is declared in the class `DeclaringClass` and the event has at least to parameters. Else you will probably receive an exception.

```
Type secondEventHandlerParameterType = 
   typeof(DeclaringClass).
   GetEvent("EventName").
   EventHandlerType.
   GetMethod("Invoke").
   GetParameters()[1].
   ParameterType;
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use Daniel solution but got the `TypeInitializationException` exception in my PCL.

The following code works for me and looks more clear:

```
Type secondEventHandlerParameterType = 
   typeof(DeclaringClass).
   GetEvent("EventName").
   EventHandlerType.
   GenericTypeArguments.
   First();
```

Comment: This solution will only work on the Action<> family of delegate types. GenericTypeArguments are the type arguments to a generic delegate type.